# FindBugs:" may fail to close stream ", how to solve it?

Tags: java, stream, findbugs

The follow code is marked as erroneous by FindBugs.
FindBugs says that *"This method may fail to clean up (close, dispose of) a stream, database object, or other resource requiring an explicit cleanup operation."*
The error is marked on the line `output = new FileOutputStream (localFile);`

But we have already added try/finally to the block.

```
inputStream   input =null;
OutputStream output =null;
try {
    input = zipFile.getInputStream(entry);
    File localFile = new File(unzipFile.getAbsolutePath()
            + File.separator + entryName);
    output = new FileOutputStream (localFile);  // BUG MARKED HERE
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 8];
    int readLen = 0;
    while ((readLen = input.read(buffer, 0, 1024 * 8)) != -1) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, readLen);
    }
    output.flush();
    output.close();
    input.close();

} finally {
    if(output!=null) {
        output.flush();
        output.close();
    }
    if(input!=null) {
        input.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Switch to [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) if targeting Java 7

Answer (score 8):

Remove all `close()` calls (and the last `flush()` call) located in your `try` block since that code will be unreached for in case of errors. That's where the warning comes from. Findbugs is triggered there to believe you tried to handle them within the try/catch block.

Also in your `finally` it's better to wrap in another try catch block so that you can handle errors there and if `output` closing fails you could still continue with closing `input`.

```
                   // your code here
                   output.write(buffer, 0, readLen);
                   // removed these since findbug complains about this
                }
            } finally {
                // TODO some more try catching here so that if output closing 
                // fails you can still try to close second one and log the errors!
                if(output!=null)
                {
                    output.flush();
                    output.close();
                }
                if(input!=null)
                {
                    input.close();
                }
            }
```

Also for java 7 and up there are better solutions. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html (thanks to @user2864740 for the link).

Comment: Agreed; there's no reason to have them in both the `try` and `finally` blocks, especially since `finally` is guaranteed to run.

Comment: @hcpl  Yes,you are right. In the finally block the output.flush() and the output.close() may also cause exception. I add try catch to each one ,then findBugs report ok.